# Install Certificate in IIS CurrentUser/Personal Store

Tags: azure, ssl, iis

We are hosting some websites on azure and some on a vm in azure. We want to reuse as much code as possible. In azure application services (websites) the installed certificates can be found in the CurrentUser/Personal store using this snippet:

```
using (var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certCollection =
        certStore.Certificates.Find(
            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            thumbprint,
            false);
}
```

I want to use the exact same snippet on IIS as well. The application pool identity is set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. I already tried to install the certificate in various places but I am not able to retrieve the desired certificate ... I have also tried to install the certificate in the LocalComputer/Personal store and grant permissions to the private key

Which Identity shall I use in the MMC Snap-In? I cannot find the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` user account there. There is only an `Application Identity` account which does not solve my issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I am creating a new user, adding the certificate to the users `My` store and using that user as app pool identity. Still, other solutions are very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use the Local Computer store instead of the personal store of a named user you would need to use `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` in your call to the `X509Store` constructor, the Enum consists of two values and in your code above you're using the other - `CurrentUser`. If you are using the certificate's private key the `IIS AppUser\ApplicationPoolIdentity` user would need access to the relevant certificates in the Local Computer store, this can be granted by adding the `DefaultAppPool` user to the allowed users in the relevant certificate's private key permissions dialog. This is accessible from the certificate's context menu, under `All Tasks` and then `Manage Private Keys`.

I am not currently sure if it is possible to install certificates for the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` user, I'm currently trying to find the answer to this myself. According to [Microsoft's IIS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` account is a virtual account created for the life of the pool, so I am starting to conclude it may not be possible to use the `CurrentUser` store for this type of user. If I find out definitively I will come back and update my answer.