# CustomScriptExtension cannot run Start-Process (Access is denied)

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl, virtual-machine

I want to install a certificate in the users ssl store. Therefore I want to run `Start-Process` with the users credentials and also set `-LoadUserProfile`. Otherwise the import process will fail with *"File not found"*.

Since I want to do this while provisioning my VM, I am using a CustomScriptExtension. The command runs fine when logged into the machine with RDP but not in the extension. I am getting "Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied."

I thought the executing user (NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM) has enough permissions do execute the command. Any suggestions?

A new user account with random password is generated and its credentials are stored in `$credentials`. The `$filePath` points to a custom c# command line tool to import the certificate. The `$certPass` is provided as parameter. Here is my code:

```
Start-Process -LoadUserProfile -NoNewWindow -Credential $credentials -FilePath $filePath -ArgumentList @("--importCertificate", $certPass)
```

This question is to some extent related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296773/install-certificate-in-iis-currentuser-personal-store).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, the SYSTEM user is not allowed to impersonate other users (via Start-Process, runas, etc.) - see [Impersonate a client after authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221967(v=ws.11).aspx) for details about impersonation.

While you could try adjusting GPOs or editing the registry (using a command line tool like ntrights.exe) in order to use Start-Process, I prefer [using PsExec (from the Sysinternals Suite)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Similarly to Start-Process, PsExec lets you pass in a username and password, but also has a -h flag that invokes the process with the account's elevated token, if available.

Your command would then be something like:

```
psexec -h -u $username -p $password c:\path\to\tool.exe --importCertificate $certPass
```

In my ARM Template CustomScriptExtension PowerShell scripts, I like to install PsExec using chocolatey:

```
Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install -y sysinternals
```

Comment: don't forget /accepteula parameter if running first time.